# App background - foreground states

Tags: ios, xcode, background, foreground, background-foreground

Is there a way i could stop an app from going into background ? Or is there a way in which i could bring my app to foreground if it did go into background ?

I'm making a showcase app for a client and the app must always run on the iPad without interaction from the user.

Comment: checkout kiosk mode. It disables the home button and the exit app gesture and locks your app. http://www.webascender.com/Blog/ID/447/How-to-Setup-Kiosk-Mode-Lock-Your-iPad-to-Just-One-App

Answer (score 0):

You can force your app to stay active using following code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

But if you press home button of device, the app will go in background. You cannot force to stop this.

In this case you can use  `UILocalNotification` to bring the app to the foreground if the device is locked, a notification appears, and the user unlocks the device or if user tap on the notification.

You can also fire a local notification whenever user going to background in 
`applicationDidEnterBackground:` method